# How to add 'lease_duration' for individual secret?

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault

I have list of secrets to be added in vault and each secret has its own lease_duration. I am able to write secret but i not getting how to add lease_duration for it.
Form my understanding it is like we cannot add lease_duration for individual secrets? correct me if i am wrong.
Or do we need to add lease_duration during the NewClinet establishment itself?
I using golang/api.

Comment: To keep the secret alive which parameter we have to use? i see MaxLeaseTTL, LeaseDuration etc. Which parameter we need use?

Comment: Lease durations are a property of the mountpoint. You cannot set individual lease durations for secrets.

Comment: Also, if you are talking about the KV secret engine, lease durations don't apply, since there is no way to revoke a static secret. Lease duration only make sense for secrets that are generated by Vault and can be revoked, such as database credentials, TLS certificates, etc.

Comment: okay, in my case for a set of secrets which comes under a secret engine. How to i add a field(i dont know which filed) such that the secrets under it will not expiry.

Comment: You still haven't said *which* secret engine you are using, so we can't give you a proper answer. Secrets in the KV engine never expire; the client is responsible for the whole lifecycle.

Comment: oh okay. I am using KV engine of version 1. please find the below details of sample secret.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193642/discussion-between-kish-and-peter).

Comment: ` # curl -k --header "X-Vault-Token: s.NtHGgdtXQipPv3A" --request LIST 127.0.0.1:8200/v1/Kishan/IND/… 
{"request_id":"63b9a780-00ef-8374-fb49-646a8aba8ca8","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":{"keys":["dummyapp/","dummyapp1/"]},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null} `

Comment: ` # curl -k --header "X-Vault-Token: s.NtHGgdtXQipPv3A" --request LIST https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/Kishan/IND/19.5/dummyapp 
{"request_id":"b3a73045-a5e2-3e75-eae4-48011d0d5cd3","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":{"keys":["Secret2","Secret3","Secret4"]},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}

Comment: # curl -k --header "X-Vault-Token: s.NtHGgdtXQipPv3A" --request GET https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/Kishan/IND/19.5/dummyapp/Secret2
{"request_id":"62980cba-bf5a-e8b2-98b3-12f96cf6a29a","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":2764800,"data":{"Secret2":"##BEGIN##\n34234234442344234\n##END##\n"},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
 `

Answer (score 0):

In the KV 1 engine the lease duration is purely advisory; a hint to clients for how often to check for updated values. The global default can be changed with a key named "ttl".

Vault never deletes secrets in the KV engine on its own, even if the "ttl" key is set.

See the [TTLs documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v1.html#ttls).